# How to break my sample into uneven categories?

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

We usually use `quartiles`,`quantiles`, or `ntiles` to split a sample. We can also use the function `cut`.

I have a numeric variable where i would like to split my sample into three categories. But these should not be evenly spaced. For example, the `quartile` function would split it to four evenly spaced quartiles. These are 0 to 25, 26 to 50, 51 to 75, and 76 to 100 percentiles. Therefore, the first three functions i mentioned cannot do the job. We can probably split the variable using `cut`, but I don't know how to do it in terms of percentile. **I would like to create a variable that split the sample from the bottom 0 to the 20th percentile, then from 21 to 60, then from 61 to 100.**

Here is a reproducible code:

```
    library(dplyr)
    set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(
  V1 = round(runif(1000,min=1, max=1000)),
  V2 = round(runif(1000, min=1, max=3)),
  V3 = round(runif(1000, min=1, max=10)))

df$V2 = as.factor(df$V2)
df$V3 = as.factor(df$V3)

    
 df=df %>% group_by(V2,V3) %>%
 mutate(quartile = ntile(V1,4))
```

Comment: Check `?cut` or `Hmisc::cut2`

Comment: I know how to use `cut` but not in terms of percentile. I only know how to use it to split my sample using the absolute values. Could you show me how to create a variable that assign for each row their percentiles according to 0:20, 21:60, and 61:100?

Comment: Do you want `findInterval(df$V1, quantile(df$V1, c(.2, .6)))` ?

Comment: or `cut(df$V1, quantile(df$V1, c(0, .2, .6, 1)), include.lowest = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Is there anyway to use group_by with your code?

Comment: I tried the following code `df=df %>% 
  group_by(V2, V3) %>% 
  mutate(test = cut(V1, quantile(V1, c(0, .2, .6, 1)), include.lowest = TRUE))`

But then it creates more than 3 categories. I should end up with only three categories. The split in the sample is different between V2 and V3 but each has their own 0 to 20, 21 to 60, and 61 to 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, and I'll admit it's not the most elegant code ever written, but would something like:

```
cut.20 <- 20/100*length(df$V1)
cut.60 <- 60/100*length(df$V1)
#define your percentile limits (this is just based on googling how to calculate percentiles)

df <- arrange(df, V1) %>% 
      mutate("index" = c(1:nrow(df))) %>% 
      group_by(V2, V3) %>%
      mutate("centile" = case_when(index > 0 & index <= cut.20 ~ "0-20",
                                   index > cut.20 & index <= cut.60 ~ "21-60",
                                   index > cut.60 ~ "60-100"))
```

do what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is exactly what i want, i was only wondering whether you could help me to do the same but by using group_by at the same time. The idea is that i have to look at these percentiles for each country and year separately. That way i don't have to do it mechanically for each one alone. I adapted the code by adding two additional variables and by showing how i usually do it with quartiles using group_by

Comment: The workflow here works with group_by as is. Just stick it in between the two mutates. I've updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks again, i am afraid that the group_by should be at the first stage of the code with the first two lines you wrote. Otherwise, the problem is that we create the three categories for all countries together. This means that someone who earns 1 million pound in the UK will be compared with someone who earns 80000 euros in Poland. While both should be on the top of the distribution in their own country, if we use the group_by in the second stage of the code. The 80000 euro in Poland would not be at the top of the income distribution of his/her country